# Ionic build android fail on OSX El Capitan - :processDebugResources

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

Well, I have a Mac with El Capitan and I need emulate and build a Android application created with Ionic/cordova but all time have problems like to `Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.`

**My configuration is:**

```
sh-3.2# ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.3.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

**On my ~/.bash_profile**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7/libexec
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
export PATH=${PATH}:${PATH}/tools:${PATH}/platform-tools:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

**Application installed:**

- Android SDK 24.4.1
- Java SE Development Kit 8 (1.8.0)
- Ant 1.9.7
- Android Studio 2.1.2
- Android SDK API Level list installed: 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15 and 14

**My problem:**

When i run commands `ionic emulate android` or `ionic build android` this return output:

```
Running command: /Users/MyMacPro/Desktop/MyApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/MyMacPro/Desktop/MyApp
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.044 secs
Error: /Users/MyMacPro/Desktop/MyApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

So, i don't know what is my error because I have install all application required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

> This solution solved Android problems, if you need solved iOS
>   problems, maybe you need learn about ***ios-sim***

```
# First, Install nodejs
brew install node

# install cordova
sudo npm install -g cordova

# install cordova
sudo npm install -g ionic
sudo npm install -g ionic

# install android sdk: android, adb, etc
brew install android-sdk

# Execute android
android
# after run android you need install
# Tools: Andoird SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK Build-tools
# Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
# Extras: Android Support Library

# install ant
brew install ant
```

Then, after install all dependencies, you can create a new ionic project
like to

```
ionic start <YouAppNameHere> blank
```

Then you need add android platform support with

```
ionic platform add android
```

And finally, you can *build* and *emulate* you project for android devices with

```
ionic build android
```

or

```
ionic emulate android
```

> You can move/copy you old `www` folder data to you new `www` folder, and
>   the old `plugins` can be installed manually using `ionic plugin add <YouPluginNameHere>`